# Host-header from requests are ignored?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, host-headers

I read the apache docs, but there is a lot of stuff, which is different in Debian [lenny, 5.0.6].

Apache ignores the host-header given by the browser:
http://x or http://x:81 or http://x.mbg.local are all served, but should be blocked, according to my definition.
The definition for x stems from my hosts file [which everyone could do this way].
I am new new to apache, but on my IIS this works as expected.
All browsers act equal [so no browser header problem].

I configured two VirtualHosts, an excerpt:

NameVirtualHost hugo:80

DocumentRoot /usr/share/doc
Alias /doc/ /usr/share/doc/

Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Allow from 192.168.24.0/24

The other VirtualHost is configured for port 81.

The I go to my hosts file on any box, and add hugo's ip-address under
the new name x. Then, x is served, although the host-header in apache
is hugo!! Every user coming from the internet could make the same!

I am out of hope now. Does anyone has any help for me?

Would really very good!

**UPDATE**

Now, I have just removed everything from httpd.conf and created two enabled sites to make things easier:

First, for nagios [should only serve on exact this:

```
http://thor:81
```

`NameVirtualHost thor:81`

```
<VirtualHost thor:81>

ServerName thor:81

ServerAlias thor:81
ServerPath /usr/share/nagios3
DocumentRoot /usr/share/nagios3
</VirtualHost>
```

but it answers on

```
http://thor.mbg.local:81
```

and even on

```
http://x:81
```

also!

Then, a test server:

```
NameVirtualHost thor.mbg.local:80

    
    ServerName thor.mbg.local
    ServerAlias thor.mbg.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default
    
    Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
```

This too, answers on

```
http:thor/
```

and on

```
http://thor.mbg.local/
```

This complete configuration is accepted by apache. I could not find a default,
which would override the configuration.

Is there possible other http server software, which makes this right? (I am coming from IIS, where this works.)

**Now:Got it!**

Thanks for all the help! I have not recognized, that all properties, 
like name/ip and ports must match everywhere. In my case, a fallback
to the default host occured!!!

I started a VM with a "play-debian" from scratch and worked it out.
If someone will see the final definition, here it is:

In debians port.conf, I have now:

`NameVirtualHost 192.168.26.92:80`

b) in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.26.92:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/block

<Directory /var/www/block>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All ##would just like to see, this is the end!!!
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.26.92:80>

    ServerName wl1
    ServerAlias wl1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test80

    <Directory /var/www/test80>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test80-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test80-access.log vhost_combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.26.92:80>

    ServerName wl2
    ServerAlias wl2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test81

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/test81>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-test81.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test81-access.log vhost_combined

</VirtualHost>
```

For a debian beginner, I feel, it is bad to have too many configuration
files, you'll loosing the overview.

Much thanks for all the help!

br++mabra

Comment: I think that is the longest question I saw here so far :-)

Answer (score 2):

In many configurations, one of the available virtual server definitions, usually the first in the file, acts as a default. The default is what Apache serves when the request headers do not match one of the virtual hosts.

If this doesn't answer your question, please give a more complete example of the config, the request URLs, what is served and what you expected to be served instead.

---

EDIT

So far as I recall, with your configuration, when apache receives a request with HTTP header Host:x it sees that there is no definition for what it should do. Nil desperandum, it thinks,  I'll serve up some stuff from the first website that comes to hand, oh look, theres a website for Thor - I'll just serve up stuff from there!

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/details.html

> The first vhost on this list (the
>   first vhost in the config file with
>   the specified IP address) has the
>   highest priority and catches any
>   request to an unknown server name or a
>   request without a Host: header field.

If this bothers you, set up a virtualhost for unknown.server.name, point it at an empty directory and set up a custom 404 that says "someone has made a hostname point to our servers IP address without arranging with us for a web-site to be served for that hostname - sorry!"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be using different ports.  I think that's the source of your confusion here.

The latest documentation for name based virtual hosting (which is, I think, what you want to do) is pretty good:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Hello !

I read this docs over and over, but the problem remains.
I just need another port [for another reason].

Independent from this, this code:

<code>http://x</code> will also point to the server.
I want only <code>http:thor/</code> or <code>http:thor.mbg.local/</code>
being served!!

Thanks++mabra